# how to autoplay all songs one after another?

Tags: iphone

i am creating a music application in which i m having 20 songs.First i have to download all the songs from my server which i am done with now my next requirement is after downloading gets over all the songs should play one after another.

To play one song m using the below code:

```
 player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Mp3filePath] error:nil];

[player play];
```

please help me as soon as possible.......

Comment: sorry i have made spelling mistake in the question its autoplay not autopsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to make your main controller adopt the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol.   When you create an AVAudioPlayer, set its delegate property to your controller `(player.delegate = self`)  Then you can implement the method "`- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag"` and it will get called each time the AVAudioPlayer finishes playing a file.

Presumably inside that method you would create a new AVAudioPlayer, (remember to set its delegate to your controller), init with the next url, then tell it to play.

Comment: can u explain me in more detail about this or give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

you canset code for  play next song in this delegate method for play next song :-
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{}